# Why my min-height: 100% looks weird on mobile?

Tags: html, css, height

first of all, sorry I cannot give more information.

The site is http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar.

I managed to get the template changed, so content fills 100% between footer and header. It looks good on FF desktop and notebook, but on mobile I see half the web in black, after footer.

Any help of why could that be?

[image: https://db.tt/LUry1V5n]

Comment: You have the same problem on desktop, too (check on a large monitor). You want a sticky footer, but that's not easy to do. Here's a good reference for how to do it properly: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?171943-CSS-FAQ-Tips-etc-Please-read-before-posting!&p=1239966#post1239966

Comment: @ralph.m Why the sticky footer?Ive already solved that giving bottom-margin a negative value for "content".

Comment: That's not a reliable way to do it, though. As I say, your sticky footer is not working on desktop browsers. On my large screen in Chrome, your footer ends half way up the page, just as in your mobile screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the viewport in your markup, e.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```